# Test Class for Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a visual page controller with save() function. Inside the save() function, there is an insert object. However, when I write my  test class, I am unable to query the inserted object.

controller snippet

```
public pageReference save() {

    insert opp;

    return pr;
}
```

test case

```
 @isTest
 private class standardOpptest {
     static testMethod void testStandardOpportunity(){
         //fill in data
        myextension.save(); //call the save method in controller

        Opportunity new_opp = [SELECT Prime_Function__c, 
                              FROM Opportunity ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1 ];
    }
```

The query line gave me a

> "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

exception.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post your extension code? If it's too big at least the constructor or wherever you are initializing `opp` variable?

Comment: might be useful to see more of your test code, too.

Comment: Can you see myextension.opp within your test method? (Depends on visibility of opp variable.) If so, check to see if it has an id - if not then a try/catch may be hiding an exception (validation rule/trigger) thats stopping it being stored in the DB. Otherwise, run with logging and see whats happening.

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing @isTest with @isTest(seeAllData = true)

Comment: You're gonna get down voted for this.

Comment: Not even the best answer!

Comment: Mani If you're not sure about an answer it's best to post it as a comment (which  you'll be able to do soon, once you get to 50 reputation). When posting an answer it's good to not only post what you believe to be the solution, but to carefully explain this or include a reference to the documentation or blogs. This will support your answer and enable others to learn from your answer much better! You can still do this by editing it to update it with more information.

Comment: @EricSSH It may be meaningful to explain why you believe this will get downvotes, and how the answer could be improved.

Comment: Sorry Guys...New to Stackexchange...

Comment: Test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create. Whenever possible, you should create test data for each test. This holds good for Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later.

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm